# Should I nest dependent outer joins in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, join

I have heard mixed information on this and am hoping for a canonical or expert opinion.

If I have multiple `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s , each dependent on the last, is it better to nest them?

For a contrived example, the `JOIN` to `MyParent` depends on the `JOIN` to `MyChild`:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31022/5

```
SELECT
    {columns}
FROM
    MyGrandChild AS gc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MyChild AS c
        ON c.[Id] = gc.[ParentId]
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    MyParent AS p
        ON p.[id] = c.[ParentId]
```

[image]

Compared to http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/31022/7

```
SELECT
    {columns}
FROM
    MyGrandChild AS gc
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    MyChild AS c            
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
        MyParent AS p
            ON p.[id] = c.[ParentId]
    )
    ON c.[Id] = gc.[ParentId]
```

[image]

As shown above these produce different query plans in SS2k8

Comment: I like using nested joins: http://michaeljswart.com/2012/09/when-i-use-nested-joins/ It may be a matter of style though.

Comment: @MichaelJSwart your blog only appears to discuss when the dependent `JOIN` is an `INNER JOIN`

Comment: How do you wish to define "better"? Personally, I find the first much easier to read - my mind doesn't bounce around trying to reverse engineer the relationship. Having `ON ... ON` twice in a row (parenthesis or not) is very confusing.

Comment: @AaronBertrand somewhere toeing the line between "best practice" and "better performance"

Comment: Way too many "it depends" here. While the query plans look slightly different, I doubt the overall impact on performance is anywhere near noticeable (have you tested it at scale?). So, in cases where you can demonstrate that one performs better than the other, use that! But I think it will be coincidence and really depend on a lot of other things. As for "best practice" I don't know that there is any such thing in this regard (except that most seasoned T-SQL writers, as I suggested above, won't find the latter syntax very intuitive at all, unless they came from MS-Access).

Comment: When I find no performance difference between two ways of doing something, the next question I ask myself is: if I got hit by a bus or won the lottery tonight, which version would be most easily understood and maintained by whoever takes over my code tomorrow?

Comment: @AaronBertrand I am normally in the camp of going with what's more understandable even if it means giving up performance. I have not tested this at scale... I was thinking there might be a significant fundamental difference in how the query is planned.

Comment: The `use plan` hint works when transplanting the second query plan to the first but not vice versa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is absolutely not a canonical answer but I noticed that for the nested loops query plans shown in the SQL Fiddle it was possible to apply the plan from Query 2 to Query 1 with the use of the `USE PLAN` hint but attempting the reverse operation fails with

> Query processor could not produce query plan because USE PLAN hint
>   contains plan that could not be verified to be legal for query. Remove
>   or replace USE PLAN hint. For best likelihood of successful plan
>   forcing, verify that the plan provided in the USE PLAN hint is one
>   generated automatically by SQL Server for the same query.

[Disabling the optimizer transformation rule](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2010/07/31/inside-the-optimiser-constructing-a-plan-part-4.aspx) `ReorderLOJN` prevents the previously successful plan hint from succeeding too.

Experimenting with greater quantities of data shows that SQL Server is certainly capable of transforming `(A LOJ B) LOJ C` to `A LOJ (B LOJ C)` naturally as well but I didn't see any evidence that the reverse is true.

A very contrived case where the first query performs better than the second is

```
DROP TABLE  MyGrandChild , MyChild,  MyParent

CREATE TABLE MyParent
(Id int)

CREATE TABLE MyChild
(Id int PRIMARY KEY
,ParentId int,
Filler char(8000) NULL)

CREATE TABLE MyGrandChild
(Id int
,ParentId int)

INSERT INTO MyChild
                      (Id, ParentId)
SELECT TOP (100000) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID),
                     ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY @@SPID)    
FROM master..spt_values  v1, master..spt_values                  

INSERT INTO MyGrandChild
                      (Id, ParentId)
OUTPUT INSERTED.Id INTO MyParent
SELECT TOP (3000) Id, Id AS ParentId
FROM MyChild
ORDER BY Id

SET STATISTICS IO ON;
SET STATISTICS TIME ON;

SELECT gc.Id       AS gcId,
       gc.ParentId AS gcpId,
       c.Id        AS cId,
       c.ParentId  AS cpId,
       p.Id        AS pId
FROM   MyGrandChild AS gc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MyChild AS c
         ON c.[Id] = gc.[ParentId]
       LEFT OUTER JOIN MyParent AS p
         ON p.[Id] = c.[ParentId]

SELECT gc.Id       AS gcId,
       gc.ParentId AS gcpId,
       c.Id        AS cId,
       c.ParentId  AS cpId,
       p.Id        AS pId
FROM   MyGrandChild AS gc
       LEFT OUTER JOIN( MyChild AS c
                        LEFT OUTER JOIN MyParent AS p
                          ON p.[Id] = c.[ParentId])
         ON c.[Id] = gc.[ParentId]
```

Which gives plans

[image]

For me Query 1 had an elapsed time of 108 ms vs 1,163 ms for Query 2.

#### Query 1

```
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0 
Table 'MyChild'. Scan count 0, logical reads 9196
Table 'MyGrandChild'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7
Table 'MyParent'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5
```

#### Query 2

```
Table 'MyParent'. Scan count 1, logical reads 15000
Table 'MyChild'. Scan count 0, logical reads 9000 
Table 'MyGrandChild'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7
```

So it might be provisionally assumed that the first ("unnested") syntax is potentially beneficial as it allows more potential join orders to be considered but I haven't done exhaustive enough testing to have much confidence in this as a general rule.

It may well be entirely possible to come up with counter examples where Query 2 performs better. Try both and look at the execution plans.

Answer (score -1):

there is no such JOIN Type called "Nested Join". it is a another variation of writing the JOIN may be for readability convenience purpose. you can see them as a "Sub Queries" for understanding purpose only.

if you are more concern about code readability then my take is, it's individual's choice what they are conferrable with.

And if you are concern with performance of the query, and "Force JOIN ORDER" hint is not used in the query, then it doesn't matter if query is written with "Nested Join" or All "Outer Join". SQL server come up with the order based on cost of joining two tables and/or result.
SQL Server does the JOIN between two sets of data at a time only.

in fact, imagine that in the second way "nested join" if SQL server decides to do the second part, "MyChild AS c LEFT OUTER JOIN MyParent AS p ON p.[id] = c.[ParentId]" and those table happen to have rows that are going to discard in NEXT LEFT JOIN. in that case SQL server has spent unnecessary resources on doing the OUTER JOIN these two and passing that result to next JOIN.

you can also look similar question asked and answered appropriately here.
[Understanding 'Nested join' syntax](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/304c19e6-158c-4b08-b660-9bba56460a8f/understanding-nested-join-syntax?forum=transactsql)

Comment: Why, then, do they produce different query plans without using the `FORCE JOIN ORDER` hint?

Comment: w/o that hint, we can not guarantee the JOIN order and as you are seeing the different execution plan that proves that. for example in the first way "using all Outer Join" SQL server might be doing any of this Two. first "MyChild + MyGrandChild" and Then JOIN to "MyParent". Or First "MyChild + MyParent" and then JOIN to "MyGrandChild".